# client certificate not found

Tags: ssl, curl, certificate, nss

What can I do to troubleshoot/fix why my curl command cannot find my certificate when referencing to it by its nickname

I am trying to get a secure connection to a bank server, that is handling our online payments, using curl. The server is using NSS protocol.  I installed the certificate from the bank into the nssdb with a nickname "foo" using:

```
certutil -A -d sql:/etc/pki/nssdb -i ccapi.pem -n "foo" -t "P,P,P"
```

Listing the cert to check that it has been created, I use

```
certutil -L -d sql:/etc/pki/nssdb/
```

with the output confirming a nickname "foo" for the cert.:

```
Certificate Nickname  Trust Attributes
  SSL,S/MIME,JAR/XPI
foo  P,P,P
```

When I am trying to connect using curl referencing to the nickname foo for the certificate like this:

```
curl -k -v --cert "foo" https://ccapi.client.qvalent.com/payway/ccapi
```

This is PART of the output:

```
Connected to proxy.ourdomain.com.au (172.21.0.58) port 3128 (#0)
Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to ccapi.client.qvalent.com:443
CONNECT ccapi.client.qvalent.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: ccapi.client.qvalent.com:443
User-Agent: curl/7.37.0
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established

Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
skipping SSL peer certificate verification
NSS: client certificate not found: foo
```

The last line: certificate not found: foo, is my problem.  I seem to be doing everything right when creating the cert in the nssdb with a nickname but when using a curl command to connect it cannot find the certificate.  If I link to the actual cert like this and not the nickname:

```
curl -k -v --cert "./ccapi.pem" https://ccapi.client.qvalent.com/payway/ccapi
```

Then the certificate is recognized but I cannot connect to bank server.  This could be because I need to use NSS but this is irrelevant for what I am trying to get an answer to.  I have found similar questions on stackoverflow eg. [CURL NSS client certificate not found myCert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789423/curl-nss-client-certificate-not-found-mycert) but they fall short of answering the question.  I do not have/use PKCS #12 certificate.
What can I do to troubleshoot/fix why my curl command cannot find my certificate when referencing to it by its nickname.

Appreciate any help

-M